# RealmJS - Displays proxy object instead of list of objects

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I am using [Realm JS](https://github.com/realm/realm-js) with my [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) app. I had inserted a value in my schema as follows.

```
const CarSchema = {
  name: 'Car',
  properties: {
    model: 'string'
  }
};

let realm = new Realm({schema: [CarSchema]});
realm.write(() => {
  realm.create('Car', {
    model: 'Ford'
  });
});

let cars = realm.objects('Car');
console.log(cars);
```

In the Chrome console I get the following object instead of all the cars in the db.

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can u expand that proxy and update the question. Want to see what it contains?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a consequence of how Realm objects work (as well as Lists and Results) - instead of hydrating data from the database and deserializing (potentially) a ton of objects, Realm gives you lazily-loaded objects and collections. `Realm.objects('Car')` doesn't return a JavaScript array, but a `Results` object - it still behaves exactly like an array, but it's not implemented using the built-in array object. That's why it doesn't look like an array of objects in the Chrome console, even though it behaves the same.

You can, however, eagerly read a Realm collection in an Array with `Array.from(realm.objects('Car'))` and that will visualize better in the debugger.

#### Background

"Proxy" objects are the corner-stone of Realm and its zero-copy philosophy. All the Realm SDKs are implemented the same way - instead of plain objects subject to serialization and deserialization, you get proxy objects that access the database directly.

In realm-js the actual proxying mechanism works differently based on whether your code runs on React Native, Node.js, or the React Native Chrome debugger, so the implementation details of these proxies are going to differ.

The problem with all this is that it doesn't display as nicely in a JavaScript debugger. Unfortunately I'm not aware of a way to influence the way Chrome displays objects in the debugger.

Source: I'm a realm-js contributor.

Comment: How do you update the values of the car object? I have tried but the object is not updating.

Comment: ```js
const car = realm.objects('Car')[0];
realm.write(() => car.make = 'Honda';
```

should work. But if you're viewing the object in the Chrome Debugger you might need to re-evaluate it to get its latest value.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems fine, I used a similar snippet in my project as well

[image: Unexpanded]

The above image is similar to what you showed above.

[image: Expanded object]

The exanded version should contain all the objects of Car. In my case the properties has key and value under object 0. In your case it should have model: "Ford" in one the results.

Answer (score 0):

`filtered` returns a Results object which is very similar to a javascript Array.

So your code should be: (if you want to display it in the consol)

```
var items = realm.objects('Item').filtered('id == $0', item_id);
var item = items[0];
console.log(item.name); // should print the name
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, just loop

```
   for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       console.log('items[' + i + ']:', { ...items[i] })
    }
```